# Curl bracket globbing

Tags: curl, web-scraping

Looking to use curl to grab a bunch of data the problem being is that data needs a range param, ie ?range=1-1, range=2-2, range=3-3 etc

How do I get curl to increment BOTH values at the same time so I get output like the above?

```
curl "http://test.abc.test&range=[0-100]-[0-100]"
```

Will do the end and then cycle back through the beginning which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Why not with a simple script ?

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {0..100}; do
    curl "http://test.abc.test&range=$i-$i"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xargs` with a BASH range:

```
echo {1..100} | xargs -n 1 -I % curl 'http://test.abc.test?range='%-%
```